# Linux - Get files/directories listing and username who owns it

Tags: linux, shell

I am creating report for usage of shared Linux nfs mount point and sending via email. I am using `du` Linux command to get directory size but I need also to have information about who own these files. Is there a way to get information like this:

```
SIZE[MB]    FILENAME     OWNER

631746  /logs1           user1                           
372477  /logs2           user2
372477  /data3           user1
191846  /data2           user2
```

Thank You

Comment: I know at some places I've worked at, the sys-admins had a tool that would do this. It seems like a #1 priority related to user space. You're likely to get some information about that if you re-post this to the sysadmin site related to S.O. , http://serverfault.com/ . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with du. Try writing some custom bash script

Answer (score 0):

Look into combining your commands with ls -l which will give user/group and other information, then pipe it to sed or cut for example and pipe on to output.

Comment: not really an usable answer, I won't do it, but watch out for downvoters ;-(. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
for i in ./*       # or however you get your filenames
do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(du -hs "$i")" "$(ls -ld "$i" | awk '{print $3}')"
done
```

will do it. Though the columns to be nicely aligned in (most/all) cases, it would require some more work.